# I s it possible to connect tableau data to populate in Googel sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, tableau-api, analytics, tableau-desktop

Can I link tableau data to google sheets? is that possible?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Tableau Desktop and Tableau Public to Google Sheets.

Desktop: Connect to Data/Google Sheets
[image]

Public: Connect to Data/Google Sheets
[image]